# Why my FpsCharacter flouting on terrain unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I editted this part of the terrain and after edeting the terrain my fpsCharacter suddenly flouting when I walk above it, I already rebaked the terain in nav mesh and occlusion but its still happening..

[image: here is the image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by changing my terrain data. my terrain data was selected differentlly thats why its happening